# Chaincode (invoke) is not able to endorse on remote cluster with all three orgs, org1 succeeds but org2 and org3 don't. What could be wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a Kubernetes cluster configured which builds perfectly when running via Docker Desktop, including invoking with successful endorsement via all three Chaincode containers in the network.

On the remote side, I'm using `AWS EKS` to deploy my nodes and I have more recently followed [this guide on deploying a production ready peer](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/deploypeer/peerchecklist.html#peer-tls). I already had EFS set up and in use as a k8s Persistent Volume, and this is populated each time I spool up a network with all the config. This means all the crypto materials, connection profiles, etc are mounted to the relevant containers and as per best practice the reference to these TLS certs is in this directory.

This all works as expected... my admin pods can communicate with my peers, the orderers connect, etcetera. I'm able to fully install chaincode, approve it and commit it to all three of my peers successfully.

When it comes to invoking the chaincode, my `org1` container always succeeds, and successfully communicates with the peer in its organization.

I'm aware of the `core.yaml` setting `localMspId` and this is being overridden by the environment variable `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` for each set of peers, such that in my org1 peer the value is `Org1MSP`, in org2 it's `Org2MSP`, etc.

When running `peer chaincode invoke`, the first container (org1) succeeds very quickly, the other two try to contact their peers and hang for the timeout period set in the default gRPC settings (110000ms wait). I also have set the env var of `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS_AUTODETECT: "true"` on my peer in order to ensure it doesn't try to resolve using the hostnames like `peer0.org1` (this clearly works for org1 but not the other two).

The environment variables set for TLS in each of the containers corresponds to the contents of the ones I am passing (in correct order) with my invoke command:

```
peer chaincode invoke --ctor '${CC_INIT_ARGS}' --channelID ${CHANNEL_ID} --name ${CC_NAME} --cafile \$ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE \
    --tls true -o orderer.${ORG}:7050 \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org1:7051 \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org2:7051 \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org3:7051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-peer/client-root-tlscas/tlsca.org1-cert.pem \
    --tlsRootCertFiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-peer/client-root-tlscas/tlsca.org2-cert.pem \
    --tlsRootCertFiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-peer/client-root-tlscas/tlsca.org3-cert.pem >&invoke-log.txt
cat invoke-log.txt
```

That command is executed inside my container, and as mentioned, I have manually confirmed by inspecting all three containers, then `cat`ing the contents of the files, versus doing the same with the above paths, and they match exactly. That is to say the contents of `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-peer/client-root-tlscas/tlsca.org1-cert.pem` are equivalent to the `CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE` setting in org1, and so on per organization.

Example `org1` chaincode container logs:

```
2022-02-23T13:47:07.255Z debug [c-api:lib/handler.js] [allorgs-5e707801] Calling chaincode Invoke(), response status: 200  
2022-02-23T13:47:07.256Z info [c-api:lib/handler.js] [allorgs-5e707801] Calling chaincode Invoke() succeeded. Sending COMPLETED message back to peer
```

For `org2` and `org3` containers, once it finally finishes the timeout, it outputs:

```
2022-02-23T12:24:05.045Z error [c-api:lib/handler.js] Chat stream with peer - on error: %j "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established\n    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:391:49)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)\n    at /usr/local/src/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:182:78\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)" 
2022-02-23T12:24:05.045Z debug [c-api:lib/handler.js] Chat stream ending
```

I have also enabled `DEBUG` logs on everything and I'm gleaning nothing useful from it. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

The three peers share the same port. Is that even possible?

Also, when running invoke from the command line, I would normally use the following pattern, repeated for each peer.

```
--peerAddresses localhost:6051 --tlsRootCertFiles <path to peer on port 6051>
--peerAddresses localhost:6052 --tlsRootCertFiles <path to peer on port 6052>
```

not the three peers followed by the three TLS cert file paths.